# What happens with the <<< bash operator?

Tags: bash

I've always used bc with the <<< operator as such

```
bc <<< 3+3
```

But I've wondered what does <<< really do? Does it echo and pipe?

Comment: It's pretty much equivalent to `echo 3+3 | bc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the GNU bash manual

```
3.6.7 Here Strings

A variant of here documents, the format is:

<<< word
The word is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input.
```

So I guess it's just a here string that is piped to stdin.